# Left aligning without extra space between words in tables

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

Here is the illustrating code:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, 10pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|m{4.5cm}|m{1.2cm}<{\centering}|m{8cm}|c|}
\hline
\centering \textbf{Course Name} & \centering \textbf{Date} & \centering \textbf{Textbook} & \centering \textbf{Grade} \tabularnewline \hline

C Programming Language \& Lab & 09/2009 - 12/2009 & Brian W. Kernighan, and Dennis M. Ritchie, \textit{The C Programming Language}, 2nd ed. ISBN:9780131103627 & 89 \\ \hline

Integrative Practice on Courses & 07/2011 & LUPA, \textit{Linux Software Engineer}, ISBN:9787030199645 & 87 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

As shown in the PDF generated, there are too much space between some words because I disabled automatic hyphenation. I'd like to leave only single space between words, without justify align.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `\raggedright` alignment for the columns of interest:

[image]

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, 10pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}% http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry
\usepackage{array}% http://ctan.org/pkg/array
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}% http://ctan.org/pkg/hyphenat
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  \begin{tabular}{|m{4.5cm}|m{1.2cm}<{\centering}|m{8cm}|c|}
    \hline
    \centering \textbf{Course Name} & \centering \textbf{Date} & \centering \textbf{Textbook} & \centering \textbf{Grade} \tabularnewline
    \hline
    C Programming Language \& Lab & 09/2009 - 12/2009 & 
      Brian W. Kernighan, and Dennis M. Ritchie, \textit{The C Programming Language}, 2nd ed. ISBN:9780131103627 & 89 \\
    \hline
    Integrative Practice on Courses & 07/2011 & LUPA, \textit{Linux Software Engineer}, ISBN:9787030199645 & 87 \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{center}

\begin{center}
  \begin{tabular}{|>{\raggedright}m{4.5cm}|>{\centering}m{1.2cm}|>{\raggedright}m{8cm}|c|}
    \hline
    \centering \textbf{Course Name} & \centering \textbf{Date} & \centering \textbf{Textbook} & \centering \textbf{Grade} \tabularnewline
    \hline
    C Programming Language \& Lab & 09/2009 - 12/2009 & 
      Brian W. Kernighan, and Dennis M. Ritchie, \textit{The C Programming Language}, 2nd ed. ISBN:9780131103627 & 89 \\
    \hline
    Integrative Practice on Courses & 07/2011 & LUPA, \textit{Linux Software Engineer}, ISBN:9787030199645 & 87 \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! Just one more question, what are the ">""<"'s used for?

Comment: @goldfrapp04: `>{<stuff>}` is used to insert `<stuff>` *before* each cell entry in that column, while `<{<stuff>}` inserts `<stuff>` *after* each cell entry. Read p 2 of the [`array` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/tools/array.pdf).